# How to find an infinite series representation for ellipse’s arc length?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the circumference of an ellipse to be the infinite series

$$2 \pi*a[1-\frac12(e^2)/1-\frac{1 \times 3}{2 \times 4}(e^4)/3-\frac{1\times 3\times 5}{2 \times 4 \times 6}(e^6)/5-...]$$

from this integral

$\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{1-(e^2)\sin^2(x)}dx$ where $e$ is the eccentricity of an ellipse

I am using the binomial series expansion $(1+x)^n$ to try and solve this, but I cannot get the  answer above because $\sin^2(x)$ is always $0$. I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: Use riemann sum.

Comment: Another way is to use the [series expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=EllipticE+series+expansion) of the Elliptic integral of the second kind

Comment: 1) As said by Tyma Gaidash, the Elliptic integral of the 2nd kind gives you an **exact** value. 2) Besides instead of $(0,2 \pi)$, use integration interval $(0,\pi/2)$ and multiply by $4$. 3) I have "latexified" your formulas : have a look at them in order, next time, to have a more readable (and prettier) text.

Comment: I suggest figuring out the Taylor series in $y$ for $\sqrt{1-y^2}$, then substituting $y = e\sin x$, and integrating it over $x$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.